# Add marker in Mapbox URL (not via JS)

Tags: mapbox

I'd like to generate a link to a Mapbox map, centered on a particular latitude and longitude, that also contains a marker on that spot. This is trivial when generating a static map:

```
https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/pin-m(<lat>,<lon>)/<lat>,<lon>,<zoom>/320x160.png?access_token=<access token>
```

with the pin-m() segment specifying the marker. When generating a link to a full, interactive (zoomable/pannable) map, however, specifying a marker doesn't seem to be an option. This URL goes to the map I want:

```
https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/zoompan.html?access_token=<access token>#<zoom>/<lat>/<lon>
```

but there's no marker. I looked through all the documentation and couldn't find any reference to a way to do this. From the docs it looks like the only way to add a marker to the map is to host a page and generate the map via JS in a script. I can do this, but I'd much prefer to be able to just add a parameter to a URL instead of adding a whole new route/controller/view/associated specs for our Rails app for what seems to me to be a very minor addition.

Does anybody know of an undocumented way to do this? Or a documented way that I've just overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't able to add a marker through a url parameter like the static API allows. You could add a marker by following this [example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/single-marker/) for Mapbox JS or you could use the newer Mapbox GL JS to center the map around a marker like in this [example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/center-on-symbol/).

I Hope this helps